# C++, Windows Service and msvcp140.dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, service

I wrote a program using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 8, and installed it as a Windows Service.

However, when I install the service in another Windows 8 and I try to start it, I get the following error:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          06/10/2016 16:15:01
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Perinatal
Description:
Faulting application name: perinatal__amor_de_mae__app.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x57f68131
Faulting module name: MSVCP140.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17581, time stamp: 0x5644f0df
Exception code: 0xc0000135
Fault offset: 0x00078dd2
Faulting process id: 0xe90
Faulting application start time: 0x01d22005ef6b29f4
Faulting application path: c:\Users\perinatal\Desktop\AmorDeMae\perinatal__amor_de_mae__app.exe
Faulting module path: MSVCP140.dll
Report Id: 2d21619f-8bf9-11e6-be76-000c29f8ce0f
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-10-06T19:15:01.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>991320</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Perinatal</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>perinatal__amor_de_mae__app.exe</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>57f68131</Data>
    <Data>MSVCP140.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.2.9200.17581</Data>
    <Data>5644f0df</Data>
    <Data>c0000135</Data>
    <Data>00078dd2</Data>
    <Data>e90</Data>
    <Data>01d22005ef6b29f4</Data>
    <Data>c:\Users\perinatal\Desktop\AmorDeMae\perinatal__amor_de_mae__app.exe</Data>
    <Data>MSVCP140.dll</Data>
    <Data>2d21619f-8bf9-11e6-be76-000c29f8ce0f</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I think VS installed something in the development computer, that is missing in the installation one, but I have no idea what is missing.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 0xc0000135 is a simple "DLL not found" error.   Since it is MSVCP140.dll that keeled over, very high odds that the machine is missing the Universal CRT.  It is deployed by Windows Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Visual C++ redistributable libraries.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145
Or recompile the application with static runtime in the project configuration (should be /MT, not /MD)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I set the "/MT", and it worked perfectly. 

I see that the size of the executable grew a lot, but, for now, it solves the problem.

Comment: This is expected as everything which is inside this "redistributable" package is now packed inside your executable. Please mark answer as correct then :)